# Count number of CCSprite added to a CCLayer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, objective-c, ccsprite

Does cocos2d has a method that returns the amount of CCSprites added to a CCLayer?

A have SceneControlLayer object, and I added some CCSprites to it.

```
@interface SceneControlLayer : CCLayer {
}

@implementation SceneControlLayer

-(id)init {

CCSprite *spr1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spr1.png];
[self addChild:spr1 z:1 tag:1];

CCSprite *spr2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spr2.png];
[self addChild:spr2 z:2 tag:2];

...

}
@end
```

How do I retrieve an array of sprites added to the layer? Could I retrieve all the objects added through addChild and test its type?

Since I'm starting with cocos2d/objectivec, please, give some examples how to do it...

I also thought that I could create an array, and, besides adding it to the layer, add it to the array also. But I'm not so sure if it's a good option.

TIA,

Bob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `CCNode` has a `children` property, which is a CCArray, containing all children. Since `CCLayer` is a subclass of `CCNode`, you can get the number of children added to the layer using: `[[layer children] count]`

**Update:** If you're not checking that sprite count very frequently, you can simply iterate through the `children` array and count the number of children that are actually sprites (using `isKindOfClass`). If you need to access these sprites constantly (eg. in every update) it would probably be wiser to also store them in a separate array.

Comment: +1, but this assumes that you aren't adding child nodes that aren't sprites.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: I don't understand. Why wouldn't it work with nodes other than sprites? It should work with any object that derives from `CCNode`

Comment: In order to check if it's a CCSprite, I'm using [child isKindOfClass:[CCSprite class]]

Comment: @bummzack: The problem is that it "works" with nodes that aren't sprites, and the question is about how many sprites there are.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig Oh yeah I see. Must have missed that part of the question. Will update accordingly.